# Qt: Salvage Double Click

Tags: qt

Here's an interesting problem I have in my application. I've got a widget ("B") which is the target of double clicks. On top of that widget, I sometimes have to display a floating toolbar widget ("A". That floating toolbar is a Qt::Popup window as I want clicks outside of it to make it go away and for other rendering requirements.

[image]

**The problem:**

if the floating toolbar is shown, when I double click the an area on widget "B" (out side of the widget "A"), the first click is "swallowed" by the popup, and widget "B" gets no double click event. This causes a UX problem where users just can't get double click to work right.

Is there any way to intercept the mouse click when the popup is active, and if clicked outside of it, "route" it into the widget "B" for consideration such that a second click would be considered "double click"?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a Qt bug, please report it.

Comment: any ways to bypass it? I cannot wait for a formal fix. This is holding off a release. I'm with Qt 4.8.5 -- there's no time to upgrade to 5.x

Comment: Presumably if you're a paying customer, you could put some pressure on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no choice but to stop using Qt::Popup and nothing worked in my case.

My app is complex. The thing is, that due to my app's purpose in life-- 3rd party components can create windows that are children of "B" widget. I have no control over their code. When I use Qt::Popup to create widget "A" the double click event fails on Windows.

On Mac: The "B" descendant component will get the double click event and the "A" Qt::Popup will auto-close. 
On Windows: The "A" Qt::popup does auto-close, but swallows the first click with it, leaving the widget "B" descendant component with a single click. You cannot double click them ever when the popup is visible.

Given this is probably an OS limitation or Qt bug, I stopped using Qt::Popup and moved to Qt::Tool -- This forces me to do the auto-closing in my own code - but at least on windows and Mac the double click passes through correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set mouse tracking to `true` for both A and B. Seems that for B will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a really not very pleasant hack to get around it:

1) Have the popup implement the mouse click event method
2) Look at the x,y pos from the event, determine whether that point is in the bounds of the popup
3) If not then use `QApplication::sendEvent()` to redirect it to the B widget.

Note I can't say for certain that'll work, but theoretically it should.